# Calculate this specific dot product

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the following:

$$dx\,dy\,\hat{z} \cdot -(\hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z})$$

I get $3\,dx\,dy$ on the first try but I want to make sure

EDIT: After thinking some more, the dot product is equal to $A_xB_x$ where $A_x = dxdy$ and $B_x = -1$ so the answer is $-dxdy$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\hat z \cdot \hat x= \hat z \cdot \hat y=0$$

and

$$\hat z \cdot \hat z=1$$